# Segmentation fault when using threading.Thread and Queue

Tags: python-2.7, segmentation-fault, queue, python-multithreading

I am trying to figure out why I keep getting segfaults from a method along the lines of the following.

```
import threading, Queue

Class A:

    @staticmethod
    def f_A(x, y):

        """
        There is a call to numpy.integrate.quad here
        """
        ...
        return z


Class B:

    @staticmethod
    def worker(f, q, x, y):

        ...
        q.put(f(x, y))
        return

    @staticmethod
    def f_B(x1, y1, x2, y2):

        f = A.f_A
        q = Queue()

        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=B.worker, args=(f, q, x1, y1))
        thread2 = threading.Thread(target=B.worker, args=(f, q, x2, y2))

        thread1.start()
        thread2.start()

        thread1.join()
        thread2.join()

        result1 = q.get()
        result2 = q.get()

        return result1, result2

In [1]: B.f_B(x1, y1, x2, y2)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Where `x` and `y` are lists. If I run a single thread, everything works ok. Any idea why the segfaulting? Is it because each thread tries to access the same function `A.f_A()`?

The strange thing is if I use `multiprocessing.Process` it also works. Why won't it work with threads?